# How to write units with superscript exponent

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know how can i write a unit with superscript.i have a value whose unit is gram per hactar `g/ha`. I want to write it to appear as follows

```
g*ha-1: where -1 is the exponent of ha-1
```

please let me know how can i achieve that

Comment: You can type out the superscript somewhere else (on a text editor for example) and then copy paste it into your IDE

Comment: @TylerLiu i tried to use sup() but it is invalidated

Comment: I meant literally type out the superscript and paste it into your IDE. Like this: aᵇ

Comment: It is hardly angular and typescript question tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the tag sup

```
g*ha<sup>-1</sup>
```

or a .css

```
g*ha<span class="sup">-1</span>
.sup{
  font-size: .5rem;
  vertical-align:super;
}
```